# Symfony2 Rendering datetime with timezone in forms

Tags: symfony, timezone, utc

In my system, database timestamps are recorded as UTC values.

Every user has a timezone recorded in their profile. When logging in, the timezone value is transferred from their profile to their session ( $session->set('timezone', $tz); ).

Most of my code uses the Sonata INTL bundle, so users see the datetime values displayed correctly for their timezone, **except** in form fields.

I recently discovered the model_timezone and view_timezone fields on some of the Symfony2 types. I can make the fields show the right values (as shown in the code snippets below), however I would like to understand how I can populate the view_timezone from the user session? (I'm guessing that I can pass in $options in some way?)

Event Controller snippet:

```
$object = <object loaded>;

$form = $this->createForm(new MyEventType(), $object);
```

MyEventType Form snippet:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('id', null, array(
        'label'         => 'Event ID',
    ));

    $builder->add('changed', 'datetime', array(
        'date_widget'       => 'single_text',
        'date_format'       => \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
        'time_widget'       => 'single_text',

        'model_timezone'    => 'UTC',
        'view_timezone'     => 'Pacific/Auckland',
    ));
```

Comment: And whats the problem? You can add your session value to the 'view_timezone' option

Comment: Hi Hast, I guess the question should be phrased: "how do I get my session value into the form?" I have a number of forms that have datetime fields. So the approach utilised should be easily repeatable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this problem is two-fold:

- Pass an array of options to the createForm method, containing your value for 'view_timezone'
- Ensure that  'view_timezone' is defined in the form default options.

I've updated my code snippets to reflect the changes required:

Event Controller snippet:

```
$object = <object loaded>;

$form = $this->createForm(new MyEventType(), $object, array(
    'view_timezone' => $this->container->get('session')->get('timezone'))
);
```

MyEventType Form snippet:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('id', null, array(
        'label'         => 'Event ID',
    ));

    $builder->add('changed', 'datetime', array(
        'date_widget'       => 'single_text',
        'date_format'       => \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
        'time_widget'       => 'single_text',

        'model_timezone'    => 'UTC',
        'view_timezone'     => $options['view_timezone'],
    ));

...

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'        => 'Stuff\CoreBundle\Entity\MyEvent',
        'view_timezone'     => 'UTC',
    ));
}
```

Comment: What if I have a timezone field in form itself with a date field and I want to use that timezone while storing the date?